# DNN 7.4 friendly URL (gclid)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have issues with URL rewrite in DNN 7.4

I have another web site running on DNN 7.3 , there everything works perfect! For example if **open:** 

http://www.example.com/Some-test-page?gclid=TEST 

it will open the same URL without reWrite! But now in new version of DNN (7.4) if i open some URL , result will be:

 http://www.example.com/Some-test-page/gclid/TEST

So for example my *AdWords* not working at all.
Find this **topic:** http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/keeping-querystring-items-out-of-the-url-path-in-dnn

In my HostSettings table , I don't have record for
`SettingName = 'AUM_KeepInQueryStringRegex'`

So I inserted the following **statement:**

```
insert into {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}HostSettings (SettingName, SettingValue) values ('AUM_KeepInQueryStringRegex', '/nomo/\d+|/runningDefault/[^/]+|/popup/(?:true|false)|/(?:page|category|sort|tags)/[^/]+|(/utm[^/]+/[^/]+)+')
```

Clear cache, restart app pool. And nothings happen. I was check `DoNotIncludeInPathRegex` value as mentioned in **NOTE:** 

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/release/7.4.0/DNN%20Platform/Library/Entities/Urls/FriendlyUrlSettings.cs

But it is same:

```
public const string KeepInQueryStringRegexSetting = "AUM_KeepInQueryStringRegex";
```

By the way this problem  is reflected to a search engine that also does not work. How other people works with version 7.4?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FOUND A SOLUTION !!! .. 

Installed this module : http://dnnurlmanagement.codeplex.com/

and uncheck : Redirect Unfriendly .. this solve my issue..

Something interesting , if install same module on 7.3 and check same checkbox , 7.3 begins to behave like 7.4 .. so may be this is a future in new version , but totally not working for me.